# Visualizer always returns -128

Tags: java, android

I want to visualize a sound file but the method `visualizer.getWaveForm(data)` always returns `-128`.

Do you now what's wrong?

```
try {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/test.ogg");

        int audioSessionID = mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
        Visualizer visualizer = new Visualizer(audioSessionID);

        visualizer.setEnabled(true);
        byte[] data = new byte[visualizer.getCaptureSize()];
        visualizer.getWaveForm(data);
        for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            Log.d("d",Integer.toString(data[i]));
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d("d","p1");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d("d","p2");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("d","p3");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("d","p4");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Last I checked java has no unsigned types. They somehow thought this would help someone and make things 'easier'. So I am a bit surprised where your byte type is coming from. Most certainly, it is a signed 8 bit value. Since -128 is in hex is 0x80 you can assume that your acquired 8 bit data is a line of 0 and your java output transmogrifies it to -128. Convert your samples to an int and add 128 to it and you get something coming close to a reasonable value.

Answer (score 0):

As primitives are signed the Java compiler will prevent you from assigning a value higher than +127 to a byte (or lower than -128).

However, there's nothing to stop you downcasting to an int (or short) in order to achieve this:

```
int i = 200;
byte b = (byte)200;

// Will print a negative value but you could *still choose to interpret* this as +200.
System.err.println(b); 

// "Upcast" to short in order to easily view / interpret as a positive value.
// You would typically do this *within* the method that expected an unsigned byte.
short s = b & 0xFF;
System.err.println(s); // Will print a positive value.
```